# How to Design a Decoupled HTML

Tags: html, css, architecture, decoupling

**Here is the situation**

Consider some websites has base components / controls such as header, footer, etc, and say that they share some common components as well, such as custom input, custom button, accordion panel, etc.

The components can be shared in multiple ways, such as javascript libraries, or even server-side libraries such as dot net dlls. The component use common javascript library such as `jquery`, `amberjs` and css framework such as `bootstrap`.

**The problem**

In order to increase flexibility, the css and javascript library used in the components may has different version than the ones used in the site. Say that the component use jquery 1.8 and the site use 2.0 because the site is usually updated often, and the component isn't because backward compatibility with other sites. The conflict may occur in javascript or css (not loaded or has different version and definitions).

In javascript however, there are several workaround such as `jquery` noconflict and/or `require js`, but maybe not in other libraries. In css, I do not know any method available.

How can you design the components or site so they has decoupled between each other?

**Side note:**

I like wpf-style semantics (despite being hard to construct) in which we can encapsulate the structure, and maybe having another element inside element.

```
<textbox_autocomplete text="First">
    <textbox_autocomplete.autocomplete_item>
        <item>First</item>
        <item>Second</item>
    </textbox_autocomplete.autocomplete_item>
</textbox_autocomplete>

<script>
     component.render(); //construct the textbox_autocomplete tag to html semantics
</script>
```

However it is unlikely to be achieved with current ability.

Answer (score 0):

> In javascript however, there are several workaround such as jquery noconflict and/or require js, but maybe not in other libraries. In css, I do not know any method available.

[LessCSS](http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage-browser-options) supports environment variables which can be used to implement this functionality:

```
@import

<script>
  less = {
    env: "development",
    async: false,
    fileAsync: false,
    poll: 1000,
    functions: {},
    dumpLineNumbers: "comments",
    relativeUrls: false,
    rootpath: ":/example.com/"
  };
</script>
<link rel="stylesheet/less" href="/path/to/bootstrap.less">
<script src="less.js"></script>
```

In CSS, simple import at-rules can handle multiple devices:

```
@import url("bootstrap-1.0.css") screen;
@import url("bootstrap-2.0.css") handheld;
@import url("bootstrap-3.0.css") tv;
@import url("bootstrap-4.0.css") projection;
@import url("print.css") print;
```

It will work like a `switch/case` statement.

Fallthrough is automatic as well:

```
@import url("bootstrap-dev.css")
@import url("bootstrap-qa.css")
@import url("bootstrap-prod.css")
```

> I like wpf-style semantics (despite being hard to construct) in which we can encapsulate the structure, and maybe having another element inside element.

WAI-ARIA can simulate this type of encapsulation:

```
<div role="application" tabindex="-1">

<form autocomplete="off">
<div id="cb1" class="cb" role="combobox" aria-activedescendant="cb1-opt16">
  <div class="cb_label"><label id="cb1-label" for="cb1-edit">State</label>:</div>
  <input id="cb1-edit" class="cb_edit" type="text"
    tabindex="0"
    aria-labelledby="cb1-label"
    aria-autocomplete="list"
    aria-owns="cb1-list"
    aria-readonly="true"/>
  <div id="cb1-button-label" class="hidden">Open list of states</div>
  <button id="cb1-button" class="cb_button" aria-labelledby="cb1-button-label" aria-controls="cb1-list" tabindex="-1">
    <img src="http://www.oaa-accessibility.org/media/examples/images/button-arrow-down.png" alt="Open or close the list box" />
  </button>

  <ul id="cb1-list" class="cb_list" tabindex="-1" role="listbox" aria-expanded="true">
    <li id="cb1-opt1" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Alabama</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt2" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Alaska</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt3" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">American Samoa</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt4" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Arizona</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt5" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Arkansas</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt6" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">California</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt7" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Colorado</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt8" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Connecticut</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt9" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Delaware</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt10" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">District of Columbia</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt11" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Florida</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt12" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Georgia</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt13" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Guam</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt14" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Hawaii</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt15" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Idaho</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt16" role="option" class="cb_option selected" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Illinois</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt17" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Indiana</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt18" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Iowa</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt19" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Kansas</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt20" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Kentucky</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt21" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Louisiana</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt22" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Maine</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt23" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Maryland</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt24" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Massachusetts</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt25" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Michigan</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt26" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Minnesota</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt27" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Mississippi</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt28" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Missouri</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt29" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Montana</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt30" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Nebraska</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt31" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Nevada</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt32" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">New Hampshire</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt33" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">New Jersey</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt34" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">New Mexico</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt35" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">New York</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt36" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">North Carolina</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt37" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">North Dakota</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt38" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Northern Marianas Islands</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt39" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Ohio</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt40" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Oklahoma</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt41" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Oregon</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt42" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Pennsylvania</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt43" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Puerto Rico</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt44" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Rhode Island</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt45" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">South Carolina</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt47" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">South Dakota</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt48" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Tennessee</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt49" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Texas</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt50" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Utah</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt51" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Vermont</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt52" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Virginia</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt53" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Virgin Islands</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt54" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Washington</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt55" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">West Virginia</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt56" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Wisconsin</li>
    <li id="cb1-opt57" role="option" class="cb_option" role="listitem" tabindex="-1">Wyoming</li>
  </ul>
</div>
</form>
</div>
```

**References**

- [Importing Style Sheets: the @import rule](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-cascade/#at-import)
- [aria-autocomplete attribute | ariaAutocomplete property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh968240)
- [List of WAI ARIA Examples and resources](http://www.eramp.com/wcag/wai-aria-widgets.htm)
- [Project Silk: Client-Side Web Development for Modern Browsers, Chapter 4: Design and Layout](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh404087.aspx)
- [Lua: technical note 11 - Require revisited: Import](https://www.lua.org/notes/ltn011.html)